# In-place rich text editor, ideally using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I"m looking to add rich-text in-place editing to a project (so people can see the results of their editing rendered straight away), and so am on the hunt for a rich-text editor that has an inline mode, or a way to use a rich-text editor for inline edits.

I've come across the neat-looking http://inplacericheditor.box.re/demos, but ideally, it'd be good to find one that's jQuery based, simply so that I can keep to a single JS library.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, here's exactly what i was looking for: [a combination of the jQuery jEditable Plugin and TinyMCE](http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/6/12/Jeditable-TinyMCE-Plugin). Am posting it here in case it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [FCKEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/)?

Comment: Thanks - looks like just the thing and I'll certainly give it a go. The seamless in-place editing mode is what I'm after most of all

Answer (score 0):

I have experience working with [jwysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) and is pretty good jquery based one. Try it.

Comment: List of such tools from googleing: http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors